# OpenGl 3.3 glDrawArrays crashes

Tags: opengl

I to improve my open gl knowledge. Well I fail horribly. I got a crash when I try to render a simple triangle with some code from my studies mixed with this tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/

Any idea why I got a crash (no further information from gdb just glDrawArrays call causes the crash). I got an experimental gpu driver on my 64 bit lubuntu, but 3D games and other code works. Not sure what I am doing wrong. PS: I am doing this for myself, no "homework" or something.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_inverse.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/rotate_vector.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stack>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

GLuint triangleVertexBufferId;
GLuint attribPointer;


void updateGL()
{

    // clear buffer, enable transparency
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    //glEnable( GL_BLEND );

    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexBufferId);

    std::cout << "Loop: " <<  triangleVertexBufferId << std::endl;
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexBufferId);
    /*glVertexAttribPointer(
       0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
       3,                  // size
       GL_FLOAT,           // type
       GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
       0,                  // stride
       (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );*/

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);



    // swap renderbuffers for smooth rendering //
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void idle()
{
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

// Callback function called by GLUT when window size changes
void Reshape(int width, int height)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();

}

void Terminate(void)
{
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    std::cout << "Hi" << std::endl;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitContextVersion(3,3);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutInitWindowSize (1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition (10, 10);
    glutCreateWindow("Exercise 04 - Camera control and projection");
    glutCreateMenu(NULL);

    glutDisplayFunc(updateGL);
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    atexit(Terminate);


    glewInit();

    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> uvs;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> triangle_index;

    vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f));
    vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f));
    vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));



    std::cout << "Main: " <<  triangleVertexBufferId << std::endl;

    glGenVertexArrays(1,&triangleVertexBufferId);

    glBindVertexArray(triangleVertexBufferId);



    GLfloat rawVertexData[vertices.size()*3];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vertices.size();i=i+3)
    {
        rawVertexData[i] = vertices[i].x;
        rawVertexData[i+1] = vertices[i].y;
        rawVertexData[i+2] = vertices[i].z;
    }

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*3*sizeof(GLfloat), &rawVertexData[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    std::cout << "Main: " <<  triangleVertexBufferId << std::endl;
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why did you comment out that `glVertexAttribPointer` call? Without it, you just enable array 0, but the pointer is left at the initial values, which might cause the crash.

Comment: What is your device configuration (supported gl version, card manufacturer, card model, OS)? I'm seeing the exact same problem on OSX with an Nvidia geforce gt 650M; Take a look at this post on the OpenGL forums: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/180761-Shader-glDrawArrays-crash-only-on-nVidia-Win32  It basically suggests that (at least) on nvidia cards an access violation exception will be thrown and your app will crash if attribute arrays are enabled but never used.  I think to get this tutorial working we need the shader code as well, contrary to the author's claims

Answer (score 1):

- glGenBuffers for vertex buffer and glGenVertexArrays for VAO
- the loop for initializing rawVertexData was incorrect (only the first vertex got loaded)
- shaders could be used (uncomment glVertexAttribPointer())

With these adaptions your code would look something like this:

```
...
GLuint triangleVertexBufferId;
GLuint attribPointer;
GLuint programID;

void updateGL()
{

    // clear buffer, enable transparency
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    //glEnable( GL_BLEND );

    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexBufferId);
    glUseProgram(programID);

    //std::cout << "Loop: " <<  triangleVertexBufferId << std::endl;
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexBufferId);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
       0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
       3,                  // size
       GL_FLOAT,           // type
       GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
       0,                  // stride
       (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // swap renderbuffers for smooth rendering //
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void idle()
{
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

// Callback function called by GLUT when window size changes
void Reshape(int width, int height)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();

}

void Terminate(void)
{
}

GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path){
   ...
   see www.opengl-tutorial.org for code and shaders
   ...        
}    

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    std::cout << "Hi" << std::endl;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitContextVersion(3,3);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutInitWindowSize (1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition (10, 10);
    glutCreateWindow("Exercise 04 - Camera control and projection");
    glutCreateMenu(NULL);

    glutDisplayFunc(updateGL);
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    atexit(Terminate);

    glewExperimental = true;
    glewInit();

    programID = LoadShaders( "SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader", "SimpleFragmentShader.fragmentshader" );

    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> uvs;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> triangle_index;

    vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f));
    vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f));
    vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
    std::cout << "Main: " <<  VertexArrayID << std::endl;

    GLfloat rawVertexData[3*3];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
    {
        rawVertexData[i*3] = vertices[i].x;
        rawVertexData[i*3+1] = vertices[i].y;
        rawVertexData[i*3+2] = vertices[i].z;
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &triangleVertexBufferId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexBufferId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*3*sizeof(GLfloat), &rawVertexData[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    std::cout << "Main: " <<  triangleVertexBufferId << std::endl;
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```